# How to extract a function signature as a type

Tags: python, python-typing

In the TypeScript ecosystem you can dynamically extract the type of any objects, including functions, using the `typeof` operator.:

```js
function foo(bar: string): string {}

type FooFunction = typeof foo;
const fooLookingFunc: FooFunction;
```

This allows for example using an existing function signature for typing callbacks.

I could not find how to achieve the same using Python. I've tried the following:

```py
from typing import Type

def foo(bar: str) -> str:
    pass

FooFunc = Type[foo]
foo_looking_func: FooFunc
```

Unfortunately my type checker (VS Code Pylance) is considering `FooFunc` as `type[type]` and does not provide any completion so I suppose this is not working.

I could not find anything related to this use case on the official Python typing documentation and I'm wondering if this is possible at all.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec is as close as you'll get I think.

Comment: `ParamSpec` isn't that close, though. It doesn't capture the return type, only argument types, and can't be used as a stand-in for a function type itself.

Comment: On my personal wishlist is the ability to write something like `foo_looking_func: Callable[[str], str]; def foo_looking_func(bar): ...` instead of having to mingle the full type with the definition of the function itself.

Comment: Indeed I've saw that `ParamSpec` but this not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe a callable protocol? Something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=02bc1f9e9dd5cddd23450b0e1f245052) (gist mine).

Comment: This would be my way to go if I wanted to define the spec first. I’m actually trying to do the reverse, inferring a callable type from an existing function. But I think that in the end this is not possible ATM on Python